# Databases - Difference between roll-back and roll-forward with example

Tags: database

Kinda new here and also learning new db concepts. I got little bit confused about terms: Roll-back and Roll-forward. I read definitions and thought I understand it. I found some little tasks about transactions and it got me confused.

Example:

[image]

Question_1: Which transactions (when system is recovering) will do roll back OR roll forward? (Maybe both?)

Question_2: How is going to look LOG file after system is fully recovered?

Comment: **Hint:** A *roll-forward* can only occur *after* a transaction has been committed.  It is usually associated with database recovery.  A *roll-back* can only occur *before* a transaction has been committed.  See https://www.google.com/search?q=roll-forward+database

Comment: Well, from my example...
Question_1: Roll-forward will occur in T0 and T2, but roll-back will occur only in T1.
What happens to log file after system fails? Does the changes take affect in reverse order or what? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point of recovery is to get the system to a consistent state without contradicting what clients have previously been told.

If the client has issued a COMMIT and the system has acknowledged it, that data must be there on restart. So committed transactions are rolled forward.

If the system has not acknowledged a commit no guarantee has been given. The server cannot know the state of the client. That work must be rolled back.

A checkpoint copies data from memory to disk. Once there it is durable (the D in ACID). The corresponding log records are no longer required and can be removed.

The log is an ordered list of work in progress. After recovery and before clients reconnect there is no work in progress so the log is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assume A = B = C = 100 at the beginning

Log before crash:

```
<T0 start>
<T0, B, 200, 2000>
<T1 start>
<T1, A, 100, 111>
<checkpoint {T0, T1}>
<T2 start>
<T0 commit>
<T2, C, 100, 135>
<T1, B, 2000, 1978>
<checkpoint {T1,T2}>
<commit T2>
```

Crash recovery:

```
Roll forward – T2 (commited)
Roll back – T1 (hasnt commited)
Ignored – T0 (not in last checkpoint before crash)
```

Log after crash:

```
<T0 start>
<T0, B, 200, 2000>
<T1 start>
<T1, A, 100, 111>
<checkpoint {T0, T1}>
<T2 start>
<T0 commit>
<T2, C, 100, 135>
<T1, B, 2000, 1978>
<checkpoint {T1,T2}>
<commit T2>
<T1, B, 2000>
<T1, A, 100>
<T1 abort>
```